# Document Layout

Tags: spacing, sectioning, fontsize, documentclass-writing

I have used TeX for almost 2 years now, so I am fairly confident with it. I have, however, never given any concern to the layout of the document, but now I face the problem.

I want a file with less spacing and smaller headings than the standard file, i.e. the "article" type of document which I have used so far.

How can I get a layout like this?

Comment: If you are using LaTeX, rather than plain TeX, there is the `titlesec` package for customizing the look of section headings and the `setspace` package for adjusting the interline spacing throughout the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `titlesec`, the dedicated package, and add to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[medium, compact]{titlesec}
```

The default article corresponds to the `big` option.

If you want more control, use the `advanced interface` of titlesec. You can try something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
 \usepackage{lmodern}  %
 \usepackage[danish]{babel} %
 \usepackage{lipsum} 
 \usepackage{titlesec}%
 \titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries\large}{\thesection}{0.5em}{}%
  \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{2.25ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}{1.5ex plus 0.2ex} %

 \titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries\normalsize}{\thesubsection}{0.5em}{}%
  \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{2ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}{1ex plus 0.2ex} %

  \begin{document} %

  \newpage%

   \section{Lifetime Uncertainty}%

    The lifetime of an individual is the key stochastic element in life insurance. %
    \lipsum[3]

    \subsection{The Distribution of the Lifetime} %

   Consider a newborn individual. 
   \lipsum[11]%

    \subsection{Survival Function}%

    \lipsum[47]

     \end{document}
```

[image]
The first argument after the optional `[hang]` (one of the proposed shapes) consists of commands for  general formatting commands of the label and the title. The second argument is for the label, the third argument is the separation between label and title and the fourth argument is for the title formatting.

More details in the documentation.

Note that if you want to change footers and headers, the companion `titleps` package lets you do it in an easier way, in my opinion, than `fancyhdr` (no marks are necessary). Another companion package, `titletoc` defines tools for re-formatting the table of contents.

Comment: Thanks. The titlesec helps a bit on the layout issue. It does, however, remove the numbering of sections and subsections. I have tried to find answers and solutions to this problem, but I can't. 
Do you know how to number sections and subsections while using titlesec?

Comment: Normally, they're numbered. Did you use the advance interface?

Comment: I get an error when I use the advanced interface. So I used the simple one.
The errors are "Undefined control sequence". "Package titlesec Error".

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: Of my codes or my "document"? (I am not into LaTeX terms of what and "example" of what is)..

Comment: A small  document, with the relevant parts of your preamble, which reproduces your problem.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries\large}{\thesection}{0.5em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{2.5ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}{1.5ex \plus 0.2ex}

\begin{document}
 

\newpage
\section{Lifetime Uncertainty}
The lifetime of an individual is the key stochastic element in life insurance.

\subsection{The Distribution of the Lifetime}
Consider a newborn individual. 

\subsection{Survival Function}



\end{document}

Comment: @Dyhret: It was due to a typo when I posted (typed `\plus` instead of `plus`), sorry for that. You should have added your code to your initial post. That said, I've updated my answer with a full example, including the re-formatting of `\subsubsection`s.

Comment: Even if I copy paste your new answer into a new document in TeXMaker, I don't get numbered sections like your file shows.
Can you explain this? Should I use another software or why don't I get numbered sections?

Comment: It has nothing to do with TeXMaker, which is just a text editor. Does the code I posted, when compiled alone, yield the same result as me?

Comment: No. If I open a new file and compile exactly your codes, I get exactly the same layout BUT NOT the numbering on the sections and subsections.

Comment: I seems impossible, and I don't see what can be happening. Is your installation up-to-date? Also, just in case, add `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}` just after `\begin{document}`, to see whaptappens.

Comment: It is very strange. But thanks for your support so far. I don't know what to do about this problem though..

Comment: What is your distribution?

Comment: Your question gave me an idea. I tried to uninstall MikTeX and then install it again. This time it, perhaps, included all packages. Now it works! I finally have numbered sections. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fine! Even with a fresh install, don't forget to update: the distribution is not updated each time a package is. If you chose the basic installer,  you don't have a full install (but it's simmple to add package when you need it).